# Is there a way to show the docstrings of a Snakefile using Sphinx (autodoc)?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, snakemake, read-the-docs, autodoc

I'm writing a package, including some python files and a Snakefile for automating my workflow.

I managed to automate the documentation in the form of docstrings via autodoc function in Sphinx so far. Now I want sphinx to "recognize" the docstrings in my Snakefile as well and display them on the website. This part isn't working.

So is there a way to display the docstrings of my Snakefile on the website using Sphinx?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out. However making your own implementation isn't that hard, which is what I did [here](https://github.com/vanheeringen-lab/seq2science/blob/master/docs/scripts/rule_description.py#L23-L42). This is how it turned out: https://vanheeringen-lab.github.io/seq2science/content/all_rules.html

Comment: There is no built-in support for Snakefiles. A Snakefile contains Python code, but it is not an importable Python module that Sphinx can use.